# Virtual Machines - External Hard Drive - Windows 98

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive, vmware, windows-98

I recently bought a USB - external hard drive, is there any possibility that I can run a Windows 98 environment on it?

If so, what would be the steps I need to take? 
Else, what requirements am I missing?

Comment: Good information here for setting up win 98 in Virtualbox https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=9918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Most virtual machine tools work with *disk images*, not actual disks, and they'll let you create an image for the Win98 VM anywhere you want. I've run VMs off pendrives, and even off network shares over WiFi.

(For the same reason, I'm guessing you don't actually *need* the external hard drive, since there's no need to create partitions, and the disk images can grow on demand, so the entire Win98 VM might be a tiny ~500 MB .vdi or .vmdk file. Moving it to an external HD wouldn't give you many advantages.)

---

Though, if you for some reason want to assign a *real* disk to the VM, that's often possible as well, though usually hidden under "advanced mode" or even command-line tools. For example, in VirtualBox, you need to [create a special "redirect" image](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well the idea is that I can access this environment remotely from my office while I keep the HDD connected to a raspberry or something.

Is this possible?